# UBUNTU Dependency missing Error return Code(1) when running sudo apt-get command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

Getting below error when installing anything via sudo apt-get install or using any sudo apt command,My ubuntu version is 18.04.3LTS

```
s for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 java-common
 openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64
 openjdk-11-jre-headless:i386
 openjdk-11-jdk-headless:amd64
 openjdk-11-jdk:amd64
 default-jre-headless:i386
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64
 openjdk-11-jre:amd64
 ca-certificates-java
 openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64
 openjdk-8-jdk:amd64
 openjdk-8-jre:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried solutions present in various other questions but nothing seems to have worked.

Comment: Your console output is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it..
You simply need to remove /etc/.java directory.

I also removed /etc/Java-[version] but this seems to be not required but if doing the above do not work try removing /etc/Java-[version] directory as well

then sudo apt-get update